# Does Windows Home Server allow you to use one set of credentials across your home network?

Tags: windows-home-server

I'm looking at Windows Home Server and I'm wondering if the users you create on the server will let you log into any machine that's connected to the home server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.  It's a mostly manual process. If the passwords on the workstation don't match the password on the server it prompts you as to which one to use.  If you use the workstation password and the password doesn't meet the complexity requirements of the server (for example, a blank password), then it doesn't update the server but lets you continue using the password on workstation (though you can expect the workstation to prompt you again on next logon).  However, if you don't update the password to the one used by the server, it will deny you access to the server resources.  So in a sense, you must use the same password and, in a sense, WHS does force you to use one set of credentials.